# php with apc+memcache+squid

Tags: php, vps, cache, memcached

I have a basic php installation. I want to install apc + memcached and squid to speed up the website.

I have run into various resouorces regarding this, but one thing is not clear.

Should php be in **suPHP** or **DSO**

What can be the advantages and disadvantages.

The server is running cpanel/whm. And I will be installing drupal with around 2 lac nodes and a lot of visitors.

Comment: server default is suPHP

Answer (score 0):

suPHP:

- executes script as the user instead of as the webserver
- runs as CGI; spawns a new process for each request
- is generally more secure and popular among shared hosting environments
- can't set php directives in .htaccess
- can have per-user/per-host php.ini files

DSO:

- loads once so a new process doesn't need to be spawned for each request
- faster of the two
- can set php directives in .htaccess

Comment: SO what should be used with memcached and squid

Comment: It really depends on your setup, how paranoid you are about security, and how much performance you are willing to sacrifice. If you are running a shared server you should go with suPHP, but if you trust the users that have access to your accounts(i.e. they are all created by you or you strictly control access) you may want the performance of the DSO.